# Is there a failed external sftp connection log in RHEL?

Tags: ssh, redhat, logging, sftp, rhel7

I have a server using RHEL latest version.

We have some vendor scripts that use sftp to grab files from another server.

This script does not log results of the sftp commands (which is bad, but nothing we can do about that because of the licensing agreement).
We recently have this server changing its ssh keys and the sftp was failing but we couldn't see that in the logs.

Therefore I am wondering if RHEL is storing somewhere failed attempt to connect by sftp to another server.
Is there such logs ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is up to the program you're using to log what it does and if/how it fails. If the scripts don't contain instructions to log failure, failure will not be logged.

However, it may also be the case that those scripts are called from e.g. cron, in which case the cron logs (usually `/var/log/cron`) should contain whatever output the scripts create. This, of course, presupposes that the crontab line doesn't end with the string `> /dev/null 2>&1`, which means  "throw away all information"...

To sum up: you need to check the actual scripts to find out whether logging is an option and, if so, to where. If they don't, you should complain to the vendor, for what good it may do.